# Replacement for Seam's pages.xml in JavaEE6/Deltaspike?

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, navigation, cdi

With Seam 2.x no longer being updated with new functionality, we have begun to migrate our applications to standard JavaEE 6 with Apache Deltaspike CDI modules for enhanced functionality.

One feature of Seam that we made heavy use of was the pages.xml file for navigation and conversation management.  This will be greatly missed as part of our migration.  Is there any suitable replacement for this component?  I didn't see anything in the DeltaSpike documentation, but wasn't sure if there was another alternative I should take a look at.

Comment: What functionality from pages.xml were you using?

Comment: Most parts are in JSF itself (for some you might need JSF 2.2). It's so easy to find all the stuff on the web.

Comment: We use just about all the functionality from pages.xml:  defining navigation flows, grouping pages into the appropriate conversations, indicating which pages require login, defining access controls on pages, etc.

Comment: I don't do Seam, but what you're describing sounds much like [Faces Flow of JSF 2.2](http://jdevelopment.nl/jsf-22/#730).

Comment: That looks similar to what I'm looking for, but it appears to be a programmatic solution.  The nice thing about pages.xml is that XML is easily modifiable and doesn't require additional Java classes to be created.  Is that an option in Faces Flow as well?